# Grails Canoo Webtest plugin: invoke() fails to send JSON data in POST request

Tags: webtest, canoo, canoo-webtest

I'm evaluating Canoo Webtest for automated integration/functional testing as a Grails plugin.

I have a REST app which I'm attempting to test, but Canoo Webtest **doesn't seem to properly send the JSON data in POST request**. My test code is like below

```
invoke( description:"Add a product to shopping cart", 
        url:'shoppingCart/add', method:'POST', 
        content:'{"class":"shop.service.Product", "name":"A product", "description":"Manufactured by X", "price":99.9}'
        //contentFile: '../product.json'
        )
```

The **request body is empty** no matter whether I use contentFile approach or inline the data as content attribute. The test report shows the data as being sent correctly, but error page shows an error stating 'JSONException: Missing value. at character 0 of '. JSON data as a response of GET request is coming back fine.

I have tested the same functionality with curl and it works perfectly fine. Is there something I'm missing in the Canoo Webtest setup?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I'm using Grails 1.3.7 in case that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I started to just experiment with the **invoke()** and seems that setting attribute **soapAction** value to true does the trick.

I have no clue why this works. The [documentation of invoke()](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/invoke.html) for the attribute says

```
soapAction
  Required? no
  If the HTTP method is POST and is in fact a SOAP POST request, 
  this allows the SOAP Action header to be set. Ignored for GETs.
```

Apparently it sets some needed request header. Haven't checked which one.

Thank you for reading :)

Cannot yet mark this answer as the correct one, but will do so when it's possible.

Comment: I checked the headers. There are some differences when using soapAction attribute. Most significantly content-type is set to text/xml; charset=UTF-8 instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. MIME type is not set to JSON, yet it works. I guess the tool would benefit from possibility to set the content-type explicitly.